# Vector and bitmap images won't align in Inkscape, why?

Tags: vector, inkscape, print-design, alignment

I have created an image in Inkscape, it will be a label for a product so I needed it to bee of just the right size when it prints out. Now I have the core in vector drawing but I wanted to add some background, and that was a bitmap image (jpeg in fact). Now, on the screen it looks just perfect, but when I print it the bitmap image goes about two millimiters down and right from the vector frame where it just while ago fit so neatly.

How can I fix this problem and why is it so? Is it really impossible to create such an image and print it just the right size, millimeter by millimeter.

Comment: I don't know why it happens, but I've noticed a similar problem when printing bitmaps from Inkscape; in my case, the right edge of the bitmap was actually noticeably cut off. (The bitmap was an image of text ending in "N", and the right vertical bar of the "N" disappeared on printing.) It might be a bug in Inkscape's printing code; you could maybe try to work around it by, say, exporting the drawing as PDF (or, if all else fails, a high-resolution PNG) and printing that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try giving "integer" positions (x and y) to the image; it seems inkscape has some problems when images are not on a precise pixel.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same problem even with multiple objects in the same or different layers.  Everything looks fine on the monitor but when printed nothing is aligned.
For me the work-around is to export to PDF format and then to print the PDF file.