# One selection with two different layers w.r.t another selection

Tags: inkscape

Is it possible to have one object at the same time on and bellow an other object?
My current output is in the following figure:

[image]

Comment: See also [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41130/how-to-put-one-object-both-in-front-and-behind-another-object-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used inkscape before but this is common logic so I'll give it a shot.

First, no, you can't have one layer be underneath and on top at the same time.
What you CAN do is make a selection of the bottom hashed layer right where you want it to be on top of the other one, copy that selection and paste-in-place in a 3-rd layer that's above the other two.

**(or you could just duplicate the hashed layer, place it over all the other layers and delete the left half of it, it's the same thing)**

I think you can achieve that in inkscape, right?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. There is no allowance for this in the SVG standard. Objects in SVG are rendered in the order they appear before the next object is rendered.

1. Duplicate the two objects <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.
2. Select both new objects.
3. Click `Path > Intersection`.

This should create a new object of the correct size to create the effect you want.

Comment: This will not get the result I am looking for. Once I apply the union, both objects will get the same filling.
I ended up solving this by creating a third object, which is simply the second half of the dashed surface, and then I superimpose it to get the effect I am looking for

Comment: Whoops. There was a typo--it was supposed to be "intersection", not "union". These steps do create a 3rd object, which it sounds like you already figured out to do.