# Logic behind displacement of notches when avoiding inverse trapping artefacts in SVG

Tags: svg, design-process, visual-artifacts, trapping

I have a question that is based on the GD@SE question, "[Is there a reason Hillary Clinton's logo has hidden notches?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73601/is-there-a-reason-hillary-clintons-logo-has-hidden-notches)". Like that questions, this question is purely about graphic design and not political.

I have read though the responses on that page and I think I understand the concern about overlapping edges creating artefacts leading to the issue of inverse trapping. **What I want to know is if and what logic goes into selecting the displacement of the notches?**

Based on the responses to that question, I am confused as to why there wasn't more displacement to the new vertex that make the notches. For example, the right column's notch could move to the right more so that that its top-left corner's inner edge was in the center of the top part the red arrow's top triangle, but the designer didn't do that. Wouldn't that have improved the work by making a shadow, for instance, less likely to cause overlap conflicts?

*Source:*

[image: Source]

*With a larger displacement:*

[image: With a larger displacement]

Answer (score 3):

It does not really matter all that much how deep the notch is, just as long that its wider than a pixel. What you have here Is certainly wide enough for most relevant view sizes. When going to use extremely small sizes you need to massage the individual pixels anyway to achieve a good look.

So most likely the depth of the notch is one keyboard nudge sized because that is extremely easy to do and most certainly sufficient. You do not want to make the notch too deep in the event that you want to use the same graphics in a overprint situation. Altough not really a big constraint in this case.

Bear in mind that the notch does not have to be triangular just that its the shape of least effort.