# When Pathfinder Divide tool, Dividing path its not perfect may be its its not pixel perfect, How to solve these problem?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pixel, pathfinder

and when i am dividing a path using pathfinder tool its getting divided but its seems there is a dotted line between two path How to solve these thing. and yes i didnt use strock here.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Actually that is a bad duplicate [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/image-looks-embossed-when-converted-to-svg) is a better duplicate. Anyway it does not matter if its perfect the pixel rasterization algorithm is broken. Adobe is fixing the illustrator algorithm slowly but it will take a wile for them to actually get it done. Expect other renderers to be broken for a longer while also read [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73601/is-there-a-reason-hillary-clintons-logo-has-hidden-notches)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on screen, the line you are seeing is unavoidable when splitting shapes apart like that.

One solution is to create a full background of the entire shape (silhouette, solid in color) and have the shapes drawn/applied on TOP of that main shape.  This will get rid of the dividers you are seeing.