# Why is there a single line of blank pixels between my touching shapes?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm working on a specification sheet for a tech company and they have a graphic that's used in a lot of their branding that I'm trying to incorporate.

It's two trapezoids that meet and form angular patters near the edges of pages.

In this design, I'm having them meet at exactly the center of the pages to form the footer.

[image: This is the basic graphic. Looks totally fine in normal view]
*this example is from the cover page, so it's extra large*

I checked and double checked and my shapes are exactly edge to edge. No space in between.

[image: Shapes are edge to edge here]

However, I noticed that when people at the company were printing test pages, a blank line (equally probably 1 pixel or less) appeared between the shapes in exactly the center of the page.

In InDesign, I can see this line, but only if I zoom in a ridiculous amount (1600% or more).

[image: empty space in the gutter]

I'm wondering if this is happening because the shapes meet in the exact center of the page.

The spec sheets are a single page design so there's not exactly a gutter.

I tried adding a stroke to the shapes, but that rounds out the point, which wouldn't match the branding element well enough.

Any ideas on why this is happening or how I can fix it?

Comment: There is a known defect in the way objects are rendered in 2d graphics thsi is  called a conflation artefact. Merge the 2 shapes or make them overlap,

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73601/is-there-a-reason-hillary-clintons-logo-has-hidden-notches this thread have all the answers and solutions you need.

Comment: @joojaa thank you! That solved the problem! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this problem:

Merging the shapes solved the issue. Select the shapes you need to merge, then go to **object > paths > make compound paths** (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>).

[image: how to make compound path in indesign]

Now there's no more blank line! (image below shown at max zoom. 3200%)

[image: merged shape.]

Comment: this won't solve the issue when the shapes need to have different colors

Comment: @Luciano how can I solve the problem in that case? (right now I only need it for one color, but in the future who knows)

Comment: it's in the link in the comment under your question, but essentially you have to overlap shapes http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73601/is-there-a-reason-hillary-clintons-logo-has-hidden-notches