# How do I get rid off small lines that appear between paths in my logo?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, shapes, path, pathfinder

As you can see on the image there are multiple small lines where the different paths meet in my logo. I asked this question: [Unable to draw logo with correct strokes and shadow](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/94764/unable-to-draw-logo-with-correct-strokes-and-shadow)

And I have tried both the transformation and doing the "Expand apperance", "Expand" and then merge. However it leaves me with the lines in the final exported EPS and also on the result. The last method with expanding also removes the gradient when I merge. I have no clue why it does that.

How can I remove these lines? Why are they there?

[image]

Edit:

It seems like it is the white stroke that does this nonsense. How to fix? I have just added a black rectangle to show the white line.
[image]

Comment: Is the entire original infinity path still present?  I have only seen this behavior when two objects touch and there is *nothing* underneath.

Comment: Also, note that in the [answer you got](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/94767/57377), this is mentioned: did you try "Art Optimized" export?

Comment: Yes, it is if I understand your first question. And yes, but that does not help.

Comment: This is really *very* specific while at the same time being *very* broad... I know that sounds like an dichotomy, but it isn't. It's too specific because it really depends on *how* the artwork is constructed it's too broad because it also depends upon the final desired output. In short, you expand, merge and remove the underlying object causing the anti-aliasing error. In this case, that white stroke.

Comment: See here for a possible reasoning... https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73601/is-there-a-reason-hillary-clintons-logo-has-hidden-notches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a visual rendering artefact from having perfectly aligned and overlapping shapes.

You can see the same thing by perfectly overlaying a couple of rectangles:

[image]

You shouldn't see the same on a raster export. This is the same exported to a PNG:

[image]

The solution is simply not having perfectly aligned and overlapping shapes. So you build in to your shapes an offset one way or the other (either expand the top shape outwards or the bottom shape inwards). You can do this with a stroke, offsetting the path (*Object → Path → Offset Path...*), transforming the object... it doesn't matter how, as long as the shapes (or the visual appearance thereof) have some overlap and don't perfectly align.

In your example the white shape isn't needed anyway; it's just a side effect of how the artwork is constructed. So on your final artwork you can get rid of it... The easiest way is to expand everything (*Object → Expand Appearance / Object → Expand*) and use Pathfinder to merge everything. Leaving you with something this:

[image]

You say you already tried expanded everything and merging the paths, but there *must* still be paths where you see the lines; there's no way for them to be there without *something* being there to create them...

An easy way to check is to enter Outline View (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>).

You should see this:

[image]

If you still see paths where there shouldn't be then you need to go in and manually fix them. Manually cut the paths and rejoin them or nudge the points so both shapes overlap and use Pathfinder on the individual pieces. Again, it doesn't really matter *how*, just that you remove the unnecessary overlapping paths.

[image]

This is a common problem. It's [the reason for the hidden notches in Hillary Clinton's logo](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/73601/52050) and plenty of previous Q&As:

- [White lines appearing in 3D extruded text](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/84111/52050)
- ["Low quality edges" when importing 3d from illustrator to photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/73626/52050)
- [Space between 2 paths in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/47342/52050)
- [Image looks embossed when converted to SVG](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/65058/52050)
- [Pasting from Illustrator to Photoshop - thin borders around shapes even at 100%](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/82895/52050)
- [Why is there a single line of blank pixels between my touching shapes?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/87580/52050)

Comment: But the gradient is lost when I merge everything. The gradient that you made in the last question.

Comment: Then don't merge the gradient.

Comment: But if I merge everything but the gradient then the whole road will be beneath the gradient.

Comment: Then you mask or otherwise cut out the overlapping part of the gradient

Comment: Ah, and that is not a stupid way of doing it? It is just because of the way illustrator works?

Comment: No not stupid at all, that's exactly what I would do

Comment: When I try to merge the paths as you described it makes the whole thing white/black depending on which one I start with.

Comment: This is my result: http://imgur.com/a/KZH6Y (I hit the merge button after selecting), could you show how you merge it with recording or update the post? Because it does not work for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61980/discussion-between-cai-and-andreas).