# Make vectors coincident in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, pathfinder

I'm a little bit confused about this situation. As you can see in the image below, I a have two differnt paths and I would like to make that portion of the arc coincident.

In the second image it possible to see that the problem isn't visible outside outline mode, but when I insert the SVG into Fusion 360 it creates makes everything more complicated.

I'm beginner in AI so perhaps there ir an easy way of doing that using the Pathfinder that I'm not considering.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi juan, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. If you have any questions about the site, have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) or the [help] to understand how Stack Exchange works. If you're left with any questions, you can always join us in [chat] once your reputation score exceeds 20. Keep contributing and enjoy your time here!

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't.

Okay, that might need some clarification. Yes, it is possible to make two vectors border each other precisely. The method to achieve it involves copying a part of one path, breaking open the other and joining the copied part into it.

But even though you can, you shouldn't, as vectors that align perfectly are prone to create errors when rendered later. Most rendering engines will render both vectors separately, in both cases anti-aliasing with the background colour. Those two instances of anti-aliasing will create a thin but visible white line between the two shapes. In your case, that would be between the wheel and the skate.

My advice would be to have the skate extend behind the wheel, as long as it's not near the wheel's edges.

A similar problem is solved in [this question about Hillary Clinton's logo](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73601/is-there-a-reason-hillary-clintons-logo-has-hidden-notches).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really apreciate it.

In case for example that you have to draw a flag, with stripes, you would make something similar that what's related in HIllary's logo to sepair each other?