# How to get rid of the space between 2 square shapes after transform them 45°

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, transform, cc-2014

Please note that "Snap Vector Tools and Transforms to Pixel Grid" already enabled and I did so much search before I post this. **I use Photoshop CC 2014**.

First I created a square 400X400 and I duplicate this square

[image]

Then I placed the duplicated square under the first one

[image]

And then when I transform them both 45° I get this space between them

[image]

So how I get rid of this space?

Answer (score 1):

It's an anti-aliasing artifact. Basically what happen on angles or curves when two objects touch, but the software still wants to anti-alias between them.

@Joojaa does a great job of explaining **[HERE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/65060/3270)**, although that refers to Illustrator specifically.

To correct it... extend one object into the other, so the objects *overlap* slightly. Or draw a third object behind the existing object of the same color, so that the anti-aliasing is done to a color rather than the white or transparent background.

Comment: I did that with my project (logo) but the problem is when I resize the logo it will break and it will not be the same look

Comment: I do not understand "It will break". That is a **really** ambiguous statement without any direct meaning. "break" how? -- This question may be helpful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73601/is-there-a-reason-hillary-clintons-logo-has-hidden-notches

Answer (score -2):

click on one layer, then go to properties and make sure that you have not got a stroke (this is the gap between the obejcts)