# Extremely thin empty space between adjacent shapes in Illustrator CC 2018

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I have a logo created in Illustrator CC 2018 which contains an icon shape created with the perspective grid tool. I have noticed that between some boundaries, there is a very small empty space (maybe caused by a rounding error?). However, this space only appears in exported files, and not in the Illustrator project itself.

What can I do to try and reverse this effect?

Comment: I've seen this issue in reverse, where within Illustrator it looks weird, but when exported it looks fine.

Comment: Can you check in outline mode (Ctrl+Y) if it's truly touching? (you may need to zoom in a bit)

Comment: Are you exporting with "Art Optimized" anti-aliasing or "Type Optimized"?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem, it's seen also in GDSE numerous times. Exactly fitting seams lose their watertightness. People meet it when exporting as PNG or SVG.

Generally anti-aliasing creates a transparent gap between exactly fitting parts. More gap can be caused by limited SVG numeric resolution. You can specify in SVG export dialog how many decimals are taken into numbers.

Best cure is to avoid exactly fitting seams, have overlaps: Insert a stroke or put something under the seam

That "something under the seam" must not have offensive color, preferably have the same color than one of the facing neighbours.

Comment: Hillary 2016 campaign logo is perfect example on how to avoid that problem. Here's and explanation https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73601/is-there-a-reason-hillary-clintons-logo-has-hidden-notches