# How to fill areas outside of a stroke to path object that are enclosed by the path

Tags: vector, inkscape, fill

I have created a celtic style knot and would like to fill in the the background. The fill bucket makes a several pixel ring inside the area but does not fill as I expected it to.

The object was several lines that were combined into a single object and the converted from stroke to path to allow for filling of the cords themselves. I am unsure why I cannot fill in the bounded area. Bounded visually, I do not know if inkscape considers the spaces between the path as bounded, the red mark.[image: Celtic knot]

Is there a way to select the nodes that bound those areas and create a new object that can be filled with the fill and stroke menu rather then the paint bucket?

Comment: I am unsure of what I changed but it filled in correctly, [completed](https://imgur.com/a/JnnLmhT) It still has some white spots in the corners but it is mostly filled in so...

Comment: Can you share a .svg file of the knot?

Comment: Here is [a dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7826xojh7dba99s/2019-08-06%20CaityKitty13.svg?dl=0)

Answer (score 3):

For working with a vector image I suggest a different workflow. Instead of trying to fill the gaps, I suggest to make a copy of the whole shape, delete all the interior nodes (e.g. by using the "edit path" menu [image] or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to break apart and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to union [thanks at @Moini for this tip]) so that only the other edge remains. This shape can now be coloured in the desired background colour

[image]

and once it is moved behind your knot ([image]), it will look as if all the gaps are filled:

[image]

(to prevent possible rendering problems, one could make the background shape slightly smaller, see https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/73608/137978 for details)

#### EDIT:

The same technique can also be used to fill in some of the holes. Make another copy of the shape and delete all nodes which should not be filled. In the following image they are marked in red:

[image]

Once this new shape is filled and moved behind the foreground, the resulting image looks like this:

[image]

(the .svg can be found at https://pastebin.com/7mp1aRP1)

Comment: There's a shortcut for removing the internal lines, you don't need to remove them by hand: Ctrl+Shift+K (break apart), then Ctrl+ + (union).

Comment: That is very helpful however to convey the encoded letters it would need to be 2 colors as was shown on the dropbox link

Comment: @RealAtomsk Please see my edit

Comment: I will be giving this a try, thank you so much