# Illustrator: Remove white lines from PDF export

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, export, white

I have two illustrator files containing low poly designs. I have exported both of them and one of them has lots of white lines in between the different shapes I have drawn (see below for images):

[image: Tiger]

[image: Panther]

I have been looking at various other forums and have tried the recommended fixes. I loaded them in Adobe Acrobat and got rid of "Smooth Line Art" however this made the images very jaggedy.

I am not sure how one design can have no white lines and the other one has lots.

Thank you!

Comment: Basically, This: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73601/is-there-a-reason-hillary-clintons-logo-has-hidden-notches

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image looks embossed when converted to SVG](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/image-looks-embossed-when-converted-to-svg)