# Unwanted cracks in my svg in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, creative-cloud

I don't get why it looks fine in illustrator but when I export to SVG there are cracks in the SVG.
[image: Unwanted Cracks]

You can see through some parts the star is gold/yellow not green.

**My settings**
[image: Settings]
[image: Star Zoomed]

**Output**
[image: Output]

Comment: For vector graphics to work they must overlap.

Comment: overlap what? is there a tutorial I can look at

Comment: Each other. The rendering algoritm used just slaps pixels on top of eachoter. But that kinda does not work as it assumes something thats untrue. So if you want to not see the backgound your parts must overlap.

Comment: How do I fix something that looks fine in illustrator? how to make them overlap, in the easiest way?

Comment: Make a yellow star and put it behind rest of your star. Anyway the only reason you dont see this is that you have a noncontrasting background and the opengl preview being a bit better tuuned. Put a green bakground in illustrator and turn the software renderer on and it should become more visible.

Comment: Also read [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73601/is-there-a-reason-hillary-clintons-logo-has-hidden-notches?r=SearchResults) and [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/image-looks-embossed-when-converted-to-svg/65060?r=SearchResults#65060)

Comment: how to turn on software rendering? is it in performance? all the setting in there are turned on

Comment: have a look around the site, there are many similar questions that will give you the answer

Answer (score 1):

This problem is common and appears regularly as questions in GDSE. If I remember right I have written essentially the same answer about 3 times per year.

Exactly fitting seams have 2 px wide partially transparent gap when they are rendered on the screen. It's the antialiasing which makes the edges of the shapes to have 1 px wide fuzzy zone to avoid jaggines. The background leaks through that gap.

Illustrator can avoid it when it shows AI files on the screen, but exported formats are different thing.

Other vector drawing programs such as Inkscape and Affinity Designer make exact seams to leak with no exporting, it happens as soon as you have 2 adjacent pieces with exactly fitting seam between them.

As already said in comments, make the pieces to overlap or insert a less visible background. You can get the background for ex. by making the union of all your pieces and color it to yellow. In that case your outer edge can leak yellow. Fix it by making a small inset with Offset Path.

The easiest way to get overlap is to insert a narrow stroke and color it to the fill color. Every shape doesn't need it, but let every seam have at least one stroke from one shape.